# Выровнять текст по центру блока

Tags: css

Код:

```css
div {
  background: #ff9438;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

li:hover {
  background: #f2efef;
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>MENU1</li>
      <li>MENU2</li>
      <li>MENU3</li>
      <li>MENU4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Необходимо:

1. Текст внутри `li` расположить по центру. Не могу понять как это можно сделать максимально простым способом (не считая ручного подбора `padding-top`).
2. Как можно растянуть текст на всю высоту внутри `li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  background: #ff9438;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.25em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

li:hover {
  background: #f2efef;
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>MENU1</li>
    <li>MENU2</li>
    <li>MENU3</li>
    <li>MENU4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Методов решения очень много. Один из

Comment: "Методов решения очень много", но пока в трёх ответах приведён один и тот же.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 у вас элементы меню спустились вниз (всего 4 элемента меню), отредактируйте ответ

Comment: Все идут по пути наименьшего сопротивления)  Можно это реализовать через позиционирование. Можно через флекс-бокс. Просто писать лень, больше кода. Возможно можно ещё как-то ...)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Можно вопрос не по теме? А какая разница между использованием `float: left`и `display: inline-block`? Какой вариант более приоритетный?

Comment: display: inline-block Использовать правильнее. За ним "убирать" не надо

Comment: @BlackStar1991 зато МЕЖДУ ним надо )))

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое и кроссбраузерное решение - указать li высоту строки, равную высоте меню:

```
li {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Разумеется, предполагается, что у вас текст каждого пункта меню будет умещаться в одну строку.

Comment: а если текст в две строки?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  background: #ff9438;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
    text-align: center;
margin: 0;
width: 24%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 50px;
float: left;
list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  background: #f2efef;
  color: #bcbcbc;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>MENU1</li>
      <li>MENU2</li>
      <li>MENU3</li>
      <li>MENU4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```